# Why should the edge of the aperture have size comparable to the wavelength of light for diffraction to occur through that aperture?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, diffraction

I have read that diffraction of light can take place at an edge as well as through an aperture - but I never found an exact explanation of this condition.  But can an edge have a size comparable to the wavelength of the light?

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more as the statement as it stands does not make sense at best and is incorrect at worst.

Comment: question edited - if it's not what you meant, edit again...

Comment: Related/duplicate? [When is diffraction most pronounced?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/652220/when-is-diffraction-most-pronounced/652256#652256)

Comment: An (old) link to [Knife edge effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Knife-edge_effect&oldid=954508943&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop)